# An error has occurred! Error detail not sent by server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, aspnetboilerplate

I am using asp.net core with boilerplate framework. While implementing save functionality, I am getting "An error has occurred! Error detail not sent by server." error on production server. On debugging, I found that the control gets to .fail() function instead of going to .done() function. The record gets saved into the database and I am getting following message on pop-up : "An error has occurred! Error detail not sent by server."

Following is the jquery used:

```
this.save = function (modalManager) {
            debugger;
            _$Form = _modalManager.getModal().find('form[name=FormName]');
            var orderTemplateId = $("#orderTemplateId").val();
            var OrderTemplate = _$Form.serializeFormToObject();
            _modalManager.setBusy(true);
            debugger;

            OrderTemplate.id = orderTemplateId;
            var AssignedProductsIds = _findAssignedProductList();
            debugger;
            _orderTemplateService.createOrUpdateOrderTemplate({
                OrderTemplate: OrderTemplate,
                AssignedProductsIds: AssignedProductsIds,
            }).done(function (result) {
                debugger;
                abp.notify.info(app.localize('SavedSuccessfully'));
                _modalManager.close();                
            }).fail(function (result) {
                debugger;                    
                _modalManager.close();
            }).always(function (result) {
                _modalManager.setBusy(false);
                window.location.href = '/app/zone';
            });            
        };
```

The functionality works perfectly on local server without any errors. So, I am not getting where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the console in the browser. It will at least give you the HTTP response code you can use to debug the problem

Comment: Have you had a look at the log file?

Comment: Version of abp?

Answer (score 1):

In OrderTemplateAppService > CreateOrUpdateOrderTemplate() method you should return an output class. And in all cases you have to return the output class. So it could be misbehaving according to your input data.

And this is a sample output what client expects:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "form": {       
            "formNo": "YYYYYY",
            "serial": "XXXX",
            "productGroup": {
                "name": "LAPTOP"                
            },                      
            "lastModificationTime": "2017-06-20T17:29:13.94",
            "id": 48961
        }
    },
    "error": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

Check the raw response of your method from Chrome Console if you have not added "success" field to the output, probably framework behaves as this method did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can get error details in [Logs.txt](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#configuration).